# Closest vector to a group of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

I was reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4410205/minimum-value-of-sum-of-absolute-diferences) which wanted to find an $x$ that will minimise $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}|x-a_i|$.

I wondered about the same problem but for vectors. If we had a set of $n$ vectors $v_0, v_1, ..., v_n$ in the real number space, what would be the result of $\underset{z}{min}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left \| z-v_i \right \|^2$? (note that $\left \| x \right \|^2 = xx^T$)

My intuition says $z = \frac{\sum v_i}{n}$ which is the mean of other vectors. But I can't prove that.

Comment: If we're working in $\Bbb R^d$, then $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left \| z-v_i \right \|^2$ is just a sum of the form $q_1(x_1) + \cdots + q_d(x_d)$, where each $q_j$ is a quadratic polynomial in its single variable-coordinate. Thus they can be independently minimized, and the minimum does occur at the mean as you suspected.

Comment: @GregMartin Nice idea! so each $q_j$ will be a $\sum (z_j - v_{ij})^2$ problem. Which I think the answer for that is exactly the mean of $v_j$s. So my intuition seems to be correct.

Comment: Minimizing the sum of squared distances will yield the mean. One can prove it easily by showing it's the only point where the gradient is zero. If one minimizes the sum of (not squared) distances, one gets the geometric median instead.